# Pass a value known at binding creation time to handler

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, event-handling

Have an Int32 value sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex known at time of binding
I need to pass that value to an event handler (cc_CopyToClip)
How can I pass that value?
I don't really use the ConverterParameter - was just hoping to find a way to access that in the event handler

```
Binding gvBinding = new Binding();
gvBinding.ConverterParameter = sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex;
FrameworkElementFactory textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, gvBinding);
textblock.AddHandler(TextBlock.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(cc_CopyToClip));
```

Background:
See that hard coded 4
That is the value (sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex) I need to pass

```
private void cc_CopyToClip(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBlock)
    {
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
        GabeLib.sDocBase sdB = (GabeLib.sDocBase)tb.DataContext;
        if (sdB != null && sdB.DocFields != null && sdB.DocFields[4] != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sdB.DocFields[4].DispValue);
        }
```

Comment: Where is `cc_CopyToClip` relative to the `TextBlock`?

Comment: @Sheridan TextBlock is System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.   cc_CopyToClip is an event handler.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Blam if it's fixed value can't you use `FrameworkElement.TagProperty` to store what you need?

Comment: @dkozl I am not finding TagProperty.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Blam, not in `FrameworkElementFactory` but `FrameworkElement`. Do `texbBlock.SetValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty, 4)` and in the event `(int)tb.Tag`

Comment: @dkozl Sweet. Please post as an answer so I can accept and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep additional value in any `FrameworkElement` you can use `Tag` property. Set it when you create `TextBlock`

```
textblock.SetValue(FrameworkElement.TagProperty, 4)
```

and in the event you can read it

```
(int)tb.Tag
```